# Vlookup between workbooks doesn't work in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to vlookup a pivot table from one workbook to another but I get the following error:

[image]

The source workbook looks like this (Sheet Piv_Repos):

[image]

The target workbook looks like this (Sheet Nominator):

[image]

This is my code:

```
Dim sourceBook3 As Workbook
Dim Srepfile3 As String
    MsgBox ("Select Adjusted data")
    Srepfile3 = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Set sourceBook3 = Application.Workbooks.Open(Srepfile3, UpdateLinks:=0)
Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet
Set sourcesheet = sourceBook3.Sheets("Piv_Repos")

Dim destSheet1 As Worksheet
Set destSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nominator")

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = destSheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set myrange = sourcesheet.Range("A:B")

For i = 35 To lastrow
destSheet1.Cells(i, 8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(destSheet1.Cells(i, 2), myrange, 2, False)

Next I
```

This seemingly exact code works fine when I use it between other workbooks though.

Really appreciate help. Thank you.

Comment: The target book is open but not the source wokbook. The source book opens when the user selects it. But the error occurs regardles of if the source book is open from the beginning or not.

Comment: Try using `VLookup(CStr(destSheet1.Cells(i, 2))` and not just `VLookup(destSheet1.Cells(i, 2)`. Or use Getpivotdata since that is what it's for...

Comment: Same error with CStr @Rory

Comment: Then you need to look at your data because your lookup value is not being found. E.g 30 is not in the pivot you show.

Comment: @Rory I figure then that would just return a "#N/A" (?). The data could vary in the content so the code should be dynamic in that sense in order to meet the requirements.

Comment: No. As per @vityata's answer, if `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` fails, it causes a run-time error. `Application.Vlookup` returns an error value that you can assign to a Variant and test with `IsError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `WorksheetFunction`, not in the two workbooks.

Try something as small as these:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMeWS()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A:B")
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("something", myRange, 2, 0)

End Sub


Sub TestMeAPP()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A:B")
    Debug.Print Application.VLookup("something", myRange, 2, 0)

End Sub
```

You would notice, that if "something" is not present in `myRange`, you get the `1004` error in the `TestMeWS`. In the second case, you get `error 2042` in the immediate window, but it works.

Comment: The TestMeAPP() returns the following error: Runtime error 13, Type Mismatch

Comment: Not sure where I would use it. Trim(myrange) ?

Comment: @user3934760 - `Trim(destSheet1.Cells(i, 2))`

Comment: It seems to work with only "application.Vlookup". However I don't know why it didn't work previously when I tried this. Anyways thanks!